# UK Sewage connection - is an external rodding point mandatory

Tags: drain-waste-vent, sewer, inspection

I have a house extension built circa 1997. Inside there is a three-port shallow inspection chamber where a shower and toilet join to a single 110mm waste outlet heading out of the house.

Outside the house against the wall there is a roddable Bottle Gulley. Upon inspection it has no inlet connections opened, the roddable outlet is simply connected to the aforementioned extension waste outlet via a Y-fitting.

My question is, at the time of building or now, did/does the code specify that an external rodding point should be fitted? I realise it makes sense, but it technically is possible to rod the run to the sewage plant from the inspection chamber inside if required (it's a straight run no bends) (and ok albeit with some mess inside) which negates the need for the rodding point outside.

I am asking because this otherwise unconnected bottle Gulley is in the way of where I want to build a step and I'm not clear whether it's a nice to have and can be removed or is required by regulation.

(FYI the length of pipe between the bottle gully and Y fitting on my drawing is exaggerated, in reality it's right next to it making almost a straight run for rodding)

Many thanks for any guidance
Ian
[image: drawing of the installation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Approved Document H](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/442889/BR_PDF_AD_H_2015.pdf) says:

> 2.46 Sufficient and suitable access points
>   should be provided for clearing blockages from
>   drain runs which cannot be reached by any
>   other means. The siting, spacing and type of
>   the access points will depend on the layout,
>   depth and size of the runs.

There is nothing to suggest that the access points need to be external.